# What is the tangent bundle of Mobius band?(It is trivial or not?)

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation, tangent-bundle, mobius-band

I know that Mobius band is a quotient space of unit square with the equivalence relation $(0,t)\sim (1,1-t)$. I want to find the tangent bundle of Mobius band upto diffeomorphism. I am not getting any idea to construct a diffeomorphism. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hint: First determine if the Moebius band is oriented or not.

Comment: The mobius band is not a quotient of the unit square $\mathbb S^1$, but $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb R$

Comment: @ArcticChar the Möbius band is indeed homeomorphic to the quotient space $\left([0,1]\times[0,1]\right)/{\sim}$ with the equivalence relation mentioned by OP.

Comment: @Zest LOL I misread unit square as unit circle.